# Relation of the expectation value of the boltzmann distribution and the "temperature"

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse-function, exponential-sum

The question is about [this](https://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.50.1411) paper. A "demon" will have certain energies, where these energies follow the Boltzmann distribution:

$$P(s) = \frac{1}{Z}\exp(-\beta E_s)$$

Where $\beta$ is the inverse temperature (the quantity of interest) and $Z$ is the normalization factor:

$$ Z = \sum_s \exp(-\beta E_s) $$

The writer of the article, Creutz, argues that given the expectation value of the energy, one can find the value of $\beta$:

$$ \beta = \frac{1}{4} \log(1 + \frac{4}{<E>}) \tag{1}$$

Above holds only when $E_s \in \{0, 4, 8\}$

Or, in the case of a continuous spectrum of E:

$$\beta = \frac{1}{<E>} \tag{2}$$

I have absolutely no idea how to find relation (1). If I try to invert the equation for $<E>$:

$$<E> = \sum_s E_s P(s)$$

I find that I have to invert a relation of many exponentials, where I cannot find a closed form of the expression. I have found relation (2), which I have included in the question.

## Question

How do I derive the above relation (1)?

## Attempts

For case (1):

---

$$<E> = \sum_s E_s P(s) = \frac{\sum_s E_s\exp(\beta E_s)}{\sum_s \exp(-\beta E_s)} $$

Apparently, (1) is a solution of above equation. The solution looks like a sum of exponentials (let's assume that there are only two energies available, where $E \in \{0,1\}$):

$$<E> = \frac{0*\exp(0) + \exp(-\beta)}{\exp(0) + \exp(-\beta)} = \frac{\exp(-\beta)}{1+\exp(-\beta)}$$

Let's attempt to invert above relation:

$$<E>(1+\exp(-\beta)) = \exp(-\beta)$$

$$\log(<E> + \exp(-\beta)) = -\beta$$

That's not a closed form solution.

For case (2)

---

Atleast we can now use integrals instead of sums.

$$<E> = \frac{1}{Z}\int_0^\infty E_s \exp(-\beta E_s) dE_s$$

The integral can be solved via integration by parts to yield:

$$ <E> = \frac{1}{Z}\frac{1}{\beta^2} \tag{3}$$

To find Z:

$$1 = \int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{Z} P(s) ds = \frac{1}{\beta Z} \rightarrow Z = \frac{1}{\beta}$$

Plugging that back in (3):

$$ <E> = \frac{1}{\beta}$$

Finds the relation as shown in the paper.

Comment: In your above 'test' attempt it's quite easy to solve, taking $x = \exp(-\beta)$, you'd just need to solve 

$$<E> = \frac{x}{1 + x}$$ which gives you

$$x = \exp(-\beta) = -\frac{<E>}{<E>-1}$$

Can you take it from here? **Hint:** I'm pretty sure an approximation has been used.

Comment: @PhilipCherian You are right, how stupid of me! Thanks! If I proceed like this and take equally spaced energy levels, I can also solve these in terms of polynomials. This is a huge help, but I think it's safe to say that there are no expressions for a lot of energies, since inverting polynomials above an order of 5 (?) is not possible.

Comment: Nah, an especially since you're dealing with powers of the exponential function, approximation is quite the way to go. The corrections would be negligible I think. :)

Comment: I see. Could you give me a pointer on which approximation technique I could use? I'm either thinking in taylor expansions or in creating some kind of iterative solution? (PS: I don't have enough reputation here to upvote your comments)

Comment: If $E$ takes values $0, \delta, 2\delta, \cdots$, then $\beta$ can be determined from $\langle E \rangle $ by $$ \beta = \frac{1}{\delta} \log\left( 1 + \frac{\delta}{\langle E\rangle} \right). $$ I suspect that either the author was only interested in $\delta = 4$ or it is a typo for $\delta$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Where can I find this proof? This is a continuous set of $E$, right? (Therefore it does not hold when this "set" has some kind of maximal value?)

Comment: If my courses on statistical mechanics are anything to go by, I'd just neglect the $e^{-8\beta}$ since it doesn't really affect $<E>$.

Incidentally, this is not a response to your actual question, but a side note in case you don't know: the strength of statistical mechanics is that the Partition Function $Z$ contains *all* the information you'd need to calculate anything. So the first step is usually to calculate $Z$. In the continuous case, having found that $Z = \beta^{-1}$, all you'd need to do is use the relation:

$$ <E> = - \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\ln(Z) = \frac{1}{\beta}$$

Comment: @MathematicalRain, This assumes discrete and equal energy spacing. (You already resolved the case where $E$ takes values continuously.) And the  computation is quite straightforward: $$ \langle E \rangle = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n\delta) e^{-\beta n\delta}}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta n\delta}}. $$ Each infinite sum can be computed through the formulas $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}, \qquad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}. $$ The final result is $$\langle E \rangle = \frac{\delta}{e^{\beta\delta} - 1}, $$ which can be solved in terms of $\beta$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you. As a follow up and very naive question, I take that there exists no such formulas where (1) the energy is not distributed equally or (2) the sum is not taken to infinity, or (3) a combination of both (1) and (2) ?

Comment: Certainly we cannot expect a general and simple formula, but I am not sure how physicists deal with this as I have never formally learned statistical mechanics. I have only tangential knowledge on this subject.